# Search function with angular js, and php not working as supposed

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

What I am trying to do is create a search function that has a text box to type the data in, and a drop down to filter the search to the column selected from the drop-down. When running all the data is displayed in the table and no records are hidden regardless of what i type.

HTTP of the search form

```
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
                    <form>
                        <label>Search By:</label>
                            <select data-ng-model="search">
                              <option value="">All</option>
                              <option value="id">ID</option>
                              <option value="name">Name</option>
                              <option value="surname">Surname</option>
                              <option value="status">Status</option>
                            </select>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchBy">                    
                    </form>
                <a href="#/newMember">Add New Member</a><br>    
                </div>

HTTP of the table displaying the records

<div ng-controller="MembersCtrl"> 
                    <table id="t01">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'id';reverse=!reverse">ID</a></th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'id';reverse=!reverse">Full Name</a></th>
                            <th>Summary</th>
                            <th colspan="3">Tools</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="m in members | filter:searchBy | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
                                <td>{{m.id}}</td>
                                <td style="width: 10%;"><img class="profImg" ng-src="{{m.imagePath}}"/></td>
                                <td>{{m.name}} {{m.surname}}</td>
                                <td>{{m.summary}}</td>                                  
                                <td><a href="#/membersPage/{{m.id}}">View</a>  
                                    <a href="#/editMember/{{m.id}}">Edit</a>
                                    <a ng-click="delProfile(m)">Delete</a>
                                </td>       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <p data-ng-show="(results | filter:search).length==0">There are no results for this search</p>
                </div>
```

Java Script

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function carHireController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('php/showMembers.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data.results;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error');
  });   
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your problem lies in the splitting up of controllers. Remember it's 1 controller per view. If you need to share data between views / controllers you can use the $rootscope, or ideally a service.

Try removing this line from your code `ng-controller="MembersCtrl"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok JS looks a bit iffy too. Have you declared your module etc?

If so then in that module, define your controller like so:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $http){

        //controller code                   

    });
```

Comment: yess i did, i did not include it cause it's pretty standard to have

Comment: Yeah sorry, just thought I'd make sure. Did you try taking out the controller within the controller?

Comment: don't worry, yepp i managed to apply the search to all column now but the think is im stuck on how to app the filter of the drop down..